# Excel formula for conditionally counting prices?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write a (what I assume should be rather simple) excel formula and having quite some difficulty getting it to work... Basically I want to:

Divide value of a cell by 3
For each group of 3 return x, for each remainder return y
Find the sum of x and y

So say I'm selling raffle tickets for $40 each, but if someone buys three the price drops to $100 for that three, and the next one is back to $40 until they reach another pack of 3...

Ex.

1 would cost 50, 2: 40, 3: 100, 4: 140 5:180, 6: 200 and so on and so forth...

Any help is greatly appreciated, excel formuals are really not my strong suite :/ If it were another programming language it would be so much easier I think...

Comment: I am bit confused, shouldn't it be `1 would cost 40, 2: 80, 3: 100,...`? Are there any efforts that you tried that you could share (this is often appreciated by the community)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the following formula:

[image: Exeample]

First set the price and discount info in range B1:B3.

Write this formula in cell B6: `=B5*B1-QUOTIENT(B5,B2)*B3` (use comma instead of semicolon (as shown on screenshot) if you're not working on a Danish computer like I am).

The price in cell B6 then updates when you adjust the number of tickets you want to buy in cell B5.

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: Remember: `=QUOTIENT()` returns the integer portion of a division.